# Rewrite using SQL Parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters

How can I rewrite this so that it is using parameters instead of string values? I know how to do it for an "SqlCommand", but I can't seem to work it out here.

```
    protected void searchFill()
    {
        orderByString = orderByList.SelectedItem.Value;
        fieldString = searchTextBox.Text;
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM SecureOrders WHERE fName LIKE @fieldString OR lName LIKE @fieldString OR addr LIKE @fieldString OR addr2 LIKE @fieldString OR city LIKE @fieldString OR state LIKE @fieldString OR zip LIKE @fieldString OR zip LIKE @fieldString OR country LIKE @fieldString OR email LIKE @fieldString OR phone LIKE @fieldString OR ccType LIKE @fieldString OR ccNum LIKE @fieldString OR ccExp LIKE @fieldString OR cwaSource LIKE @fieldString OR cwaJoined LIKE @fieldString OR length LIKE @fieldString OR delivery LIKE @fieldString OR price LIKE @fieldString OR url LIKE @fieldString ORDER BY @orderByString";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, connection);
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fieldString", fieldString);
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderByString", orderByString);
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "SecureOrders");

            DataView source = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
            DefaultGrid.DataSource = source;
            DefaultGrid.DataBind();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Here is my other method where I AM using parameters (just to show you I do know how to use them slightly)

```
    protected void updateCheck(bool checkValue, int identity)
    {
        string checkStatement = "UPDATE dbo.SecureOrders SET processed = @Processed WHERE IdentityColumn LIKE @identity";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        using (SqlCommand _check = new SqlCommand(checkStatement, connection))
        {
            _check.Parameters.Add("@Processed", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = checkValue;
            _check.Parameters.Add("@identity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = identity;
            connection.Open();
            _check.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I take it this is vb.net? You should add the language you're using to the question's tags.

Comment: @Neil, it could be very error-nous VB :D

Comment: if you are using a using statement with your connection you do NOT have to .Close the connection. .Dispose will call .Close()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances of `SqlDataAdapter` have a property called `SelectCommand` that you can attach parameters to:

```
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(someQuery, someConnection);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someParam", someVar);
```

Comment: I've updated my first bit of code...now I'm getting an error saying "The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name."....any thoughts??

Comment: I don't believe the `ORDER BY` clause can accept a variable. You might want to start another question specific to doing so - but check for duplicates first. Someone has probably already asked that.